# Why won't my image move up?

Tags: html, image, css

I can't get this image to move up for the life of me.  I've tried everything but it doesn't work.  I want my picture to be aligned with the `PV` pic, horizontal to it.

I want my `HP` image moved straight up vertically so it be aligned with my `PV` image horizontally.

Here's my `index.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
 <title>Website</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.js"></script>
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.6.16/browser.js"></script>
</head>

<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Portfolio</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">About</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Contact</button>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <img src="./pictures/skyline.jpg" class="mainPic"></img></br>
</header>

<body class="content">
  <nav>
    <h2><u>Portfolio</u></h2>

    <li>
      <!-- PV -->
      <div class="container">


        <img class="pvPic" src="./pictures/portfolioPic1.png"></img>


        <div class="middlePv">
          <div class="pvText">Menu for catering company.</div>
        </div>

      </div>

      <!-- WFAFA -->
      <div class="container">
        <img src="./pictures/WFAFA.png" class="WFAFAPic img-rounded"></img>
        <div class="middleWFAFA">
          <div class="WFAFAText">Worlds first automated financial advisor.</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Hunts Points Shipyard LLC -->

      <div class="container2">
        <img src="./pictures/HP.png" class="HPPic img-rounded"></img>
        <div class="middleHP">
          <div class="HPText">Hunts Point Seaport and Shipyard LLC company website.</div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </li>

  </nav>
</body>


</html>
```

Here's my `index.css` file:

```
html {
  text-align: center;
}
/* PV */
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.pvPic {
  display: block;
  max-width: 30%;
  height: auto;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: .5s ease;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.middlePv {
  transition: .5s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 16%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}

.container:hover .pvPic {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.container:hover .middlePv {
  opacity: 1;
}

.pvText {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 16px 32px;
}

/* WFAFA */

.container {
  position: relative;
}

.WFAFAPic {
  display: block;
  max-width: 30%;
  height: auto;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: .5s ease;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.middleWFAFA {
  transition: .5s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 16%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}

.container:hover .WFAFAPic {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.container:hover .middleWFAFA {
  opacity: 1;
}

.WFAFAText {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 16px 32px;
}

/* HP Shipyard */

.container {
  position: relative;
}

.HPPic {
  display: block;
  max-width: 30%;
  height: auto;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: .5s ease;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.middleHP {
  transition: .5s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 49%;
  left: 87%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}

.container:hover .HPPic {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.container:hover .middleHP {
  opacity: 1;
}

.HPText {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 16px 32px;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question for easy understanding. Which picture do you want to align with `PV`

Comment: @OkeTega I apologize.  I want `HP` to line up with `PV`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, your question should contain a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example, [here's how](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @hungerstar I want my `HP` image moved straight up vertically so it be aligned with my `PV` image.  I can't make it more clear than that.

Comment: @hungerstar If asking to move an image vertically isn't minimal, complete and verifiable (my code is right there) then I'm truly worried for the human race.

Comment: @hungerstar Well, now I see why SOs credibility is plummeting daily.  Everyday I see questions getting down-voted, chewed up, stepped on, spit out, and ridiculed, honest questions from beginners.  My clarity on this question couldn't get anymore simpler nor magnified.  All I need is an image to move up.  That's it.

Comment: you're using 2 div containers. use 1 and then use row

Comment: @yabva89 you're quite dramatic. Many of the questions you speak of are poorly asked with little/proper code to aid in an answer. Many of those questions could be answered with a simple internet query and have been asked before on StackOverflow.

Comment: Yeah, I'm being quite "dramatic" for sure.  That's why this question has 3 up-votes.

Comment: @yabva89 up votes have nothing to do with how you respond in the comments.

Comment: @yabva89 You're right, it doesn't have anything to do with how I respond in comments.  It has everything to do with how clear it was in terms of moving an image straight up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always try using your browsers developers tool to check for bugs or errors before making conclusions. In your `css`, the `.container` has a `width: 100%` full screen. Not given any `width` at all is the same as telling it to contain full screen.

I advice that you adjust your code if you want `HP` to be side by side with `PV`or any of the pic at all to align side by side, you should use floats and try putting both of them in a single container or different containers with specific `width: 50%` and float the two `img` side by side.